# Derivative of complex logarithm of analytic function: can it be analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, logarithms

Let $f(z)$ be analytic in a certain open set of $\mathbb{C}$.
I am interested in the object
$$
g(z)\equiv g(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\log~f(x+\mathrm{i}h(x,y))
$$
where $\log$ is a chosen branch of the complex logarithm, and $h(x,y)$ a well-behaved function.

Can the branch be always chosen in such a way that $g(z)$ is analytic in the same open set of $\mathbb{C}$ as $f(z)$?

For example, if $\log\equiv \mathrm{Log}$ (the principal branch), and $f(t)=e^t$, we get that
$$
\mathrm{Log}e^{f(\cdot)} = f(\cdot)+2\pi\mathrm{i}[n(x,y)]\qquad (\star)
$$
where $[.]$ is the floor function, and $n(x,y)$ is a certain function of $x$ and $y$. So, in general, the r.h.s. of ($\star$) is not everywhere differentiable. I am asking if you can always re-define the branch of the complex logarithm in such a way that (for instance) the spurious, non-differentiable phase term in ($\star$) disappears.

Comment: Doesn't that imply $g(z)=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$?

Comment: @Mindlack sorry, I am editing now...

Comment: so you definitely mean $d/dx$? I would suggest using $\partial/\partial x$ to make it clear you don't mean the single-variable complex derivative $d/dz$.

Comment: $f(x+ih(x))$ is not analytic in general, so you cannot expect $g$ to be analytic.

Comment: @MartinR uhm... what if I assume that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is such that $x+\mathrm{i}h(x)$ belongs to the open set in which $f(z)$ is assumed analytic?

Comment: An analytic function which depends only on $x$ is necessarily constant, due to the Cauchy  Riemann equations.

Comment: @MartinR ok, sorry, I understand where the problem is...editing again now

Comment: Re your edit: It boils down to whether $(x, y) \mapsto x + i h(x, y)$ is analytic or not, and again, that can be verified with the Cauchy Riemann equations.